# CMake communicate to server error occurred

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I'm building a project which needs some NDK code, but here's the problem makes me crazy for last few days.

It's just an empty project using NDK which created by following AS guide, and changed nothing.

---

Environment:

- Android Studio 3.2.1
- Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
- JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
- JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- Windows 10 10.0
- CMake Version 3.10.2.4988404 (Downloaded by SDK Manager)

Following is the hint:

```
Support for CMake 3.7 and higher is a preview feature. To report a bug, see https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html
The CompileOptions.bootClasspath property has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the CompileOptions.bootstrapClasspath property instead.
Support for CMake 3.7 and higher is a preview feature. To report a bug, see https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html


[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"supportedProtocolVersions":[{"isExperimental":true,"major":1,"minor":1}],"type":"hello"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Error occurred while communicating with CMake server. Check log C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\MyApplication\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a\cmake_server_log.txt for additional information.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 7s
Error occurred while communicating with CMake server. Check log C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\MyApplication\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a\cmake_server_log.txt for additional information.
```

I've already checked all the posts in this site and many other sites. Tried to Reinstall AS/SDK/NDK/gradle/tools... None of those answers work.

Comment: Did you install CMake from SDK manager?  Goto the SDK Manager --> Android SDK --> SDK Tools --> CMake.

Comment: Sure, It's downloaded from SDK manager

Comment: Finally, I copied a 3.6.xx folder from my colleague, then deleted 3.10.xx folder. 

God... it work

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54623127/8034839 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54473346/8034839

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar as Oliver.Wong, and it worked for me. I uninstalled Cmake directly from AndroidStudio (my version was 3.10.xx). And then I installed Cmake 3.6xx from the command line ("yourSdkPath"/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager/ "cmake;3.6.4111459")

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
externalNativeBuild { 
    cmake { 
        ...
        version "3.10.2"
        ...
    } 
}
```

Or just remove the newer version of CMake 3.10.2, and fallback to 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704920/target-native-lib-is-not-a-directory/54932923#54932923) could help. For this case, please try use Studio/gradle plugin version 3.3.1+.