# which cmake will Android plugin use?

Tags: android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

With Android Studio 3.3 I use native (C++) library, which I built with CMake. The Android plugin (v. 3.2.1) will choose the 'builtin' or 'external' cmake, depending on the configuration of `externalNativeBuild`, as documented at [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code#use_a_custom_cmake_version).

I want to add an extra custom task (install) that should use the same **cmake** version as the Android Plugin. But even with the 'builtin' cmake, it's not clear what the path is. I can find `android.sdkDirectory`, but even there I have today `sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459` and `sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404`, and for some strange reason, some of my projects choose **3.6**, while others use **3.10**. This contradicts the official the release notes for Android Studio that *"Gradle still uses version 3.6.0 by default"*, but well…

How can I decide which to use, without reimplementing the Android Plugin's obscure logic?

One workaround that may help, parse the first line of the generated file `.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/cmake_build_command.txt`:

```
Executable : C:\local\Android\sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe
```

This still needs some adjustments, because the later versions of build tools will use `.cxx` instead of `.externalNativeBuild`; the build variant names may be different too.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code#use_a_custom_cmake_version

Comment: @Michael, the question was whether I can get this info from the Android Plugin instead of reimplementing its obscure logic.

Comment: Ok. Then maybe you should remove the _"How can I decide which to use, without reimplementing the Android Plugin's obscure logic?"_ part, because that's what I was replying to.

Comment: I am sorry that I did not originally explain this clear enough. The problem with the logic that you and [shizhen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8034839/shizhen) both cited is that the [document](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code#use_a_custom_cmake_version) does not explain how they choose between `sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459` and `sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404`.

Comment: _"the document does not explain how they choose between sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459 and sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404"_. But they do: _"Projects that don't set a specific CMake version in build.gradle are built with CMake 3.6.0. To use the later included version, specify CMake version 3.10.2 in your module's build.gradle file"_

Comment: @Michael, this is an example of not-up-to-date documentation. Try it yourself. Today, SDK Manager will install cmake 3.10 for you, and a new project will happily use it, without explicit settings in **build.gradle**.

Comment: Yeah it's entirely possible that they changed the default in some newer plugin. Although the release notes for Android Studio 3.3 explicitly states that _"Gradle still uses version 3.6.0 by default"_. Are you using some beta/canary version? Obviously there has to be some difference between the environments on your two machines; if they were truly identical you would get identical results. For all we know, even if things _look_ the same, Google could have released a new build of some plugin without bumping the version number,

Comment: I suggest to read the source code, it describes the (not so simple) algorithm to find the right version and location: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/internal/cxx/configure/CmakeLocator.kt

Comment: @Snicolas it's more complicated than that, because this algorithm is a *moving target*. The best solution I have, is to set the cmake version explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio will pick up the **latest CMake version** under `sdk\cmake`, but you can  configure your particular version from

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        ...
        version "cmake-version"
    }
}
```

And specify our custom CMake director as below inside `local.properties`

```
cmake.dir="path-to-cmake"
```

Or, you can choose **NOT to upgrade your CMake from SDK Manager** (just to delete the `sdk\cmake\<version to delete>` folder will be fine) so that you can stick to the CMake version your project is comfortable with.

Comment: *“will pick up the latest CMake version”* — on my machine, one project used 3.6 and the other used 3.10.

Comment: My question was whether I can get this info from the Android Plugin instead of reimplementing its obscure logic.